# As an African married to Polish lady, what are the conditions for living and working in Norway?

Tags: family, relocation

My name is George, I am an African, married to a Polish lady, we have a child together. I  have a residence card( but not on the bases of marriage) what are the conditions i should be expecting when going to live and work in Norway? I mean documentations and rights to live and work in Norway

Comment: Would you be moving there together, or would it be just you with her+child living elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, we'll be moving together but I will have to go first to settle the issue of accommodation and others, and then she and the baby will join me later

Comment: VTC: add'l info would be needed to sufficiently respond to this query (residence card from where, based on what as it is unrelated to the marriage, are they in the EU ... etc.); too little to give accurate guidance